# No se encuentra la columna dbo de la función escalar o el nombre es ambiguo

Tags: sql-server, funciones

Esta es la función escalar que me arroja este mensaje. La función se crea muy bien, pero cuando la invoco dentro de un Select aparece ese mensaje.

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID('GXPRFuncGetRuta') IS NOT NULL
DROP FUNCTION GXPRFuncGetRuta
GO


CREATE FUNCTION GXPRFuncGetRuta()
RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
BEGIN
DECLARE @RUT VARCHAR(200)
SELECT @RUT = from SY01200 ia inner join DYNAMICS..SY01500 ci
 on ia.Master_Type = 'CMP'and ci.INTERID = DB_NAME()
and ia.Master_ID = ci.INTERID
and adrscode in( 'MAIN','PRINCIPAL')
RETURN @RUT
END

GO
```

Comment: ¿Cómo la estás invocando?

Comment: Estas ejecutando tal cual pusiste aca? que version de sql server utilizas?. Hasta donde recuerdo, en sql server, va un as entre el return y el begin del comiendo. Tengo entendido que cuando llamas a una función escalar en un select se tiene que colocar el propietario y el nombre de la funcion, o sea, quedaria algo como dbo.NombreFuncion.

Comment: Para la creación de la función me base de un libro cuyo autor es Manuel Torres Remon y no colocaba ningus AS entre el return y el begin. Ademas me creo la función.  
El tema cuando lo invoco lo hago con el propietario y coloco dentro del select dbo.GXPRFuncGetRuta(). 
Me pueden seguir ayudando. Gracias.

Comment: Es probable que el usuario con el que te conectas utilice otro esquema por defecto (y no el `dbo`, que es el más habitual), y por tanto, habría que invocarla con el nombre de ese esquema. También podemos forzar a que se cree en `dbo`, si el usuario tiene permisos. ¿Qué ocurre si agregas el esquema a la sentencia de creación: `CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GXPRFuncGetRuta()`?

Comment: Era una tontería. Volvi a ejecutar sql server management studio al otro día y ya está. Ya no me da error cuando invoco la función. Anda todo bien.